# li without </li> in Jade lang

Tags: html, pug

I'm trying to write this code:

```
  <ul>
     <li> 1
     <li> 2
     <li> 3
```

Whithout   `</li>`.
How would this `html` code look on the `Jade` lang?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for not wanting closing tags? I know they're [*optional*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) but it's still not great.

Comment: That being said, the closing tag for `<ul>` is **not** optional.

Comment: Yes. I need `</ul>`.
But, don't need `</li>`.
 I should do this, because between `li` there are indents(spaces). I can't write `font-size: 0` on `ul`. Because in `li` child is necessary to specify the `font-size` in `em`

Comment: But I can't see how that has anything to do with whether or not you close your `<li>` tags?

Comment: Whithout `</li>` doesn't exist "spaces" between `<li>`
It's neccessary, when you can't set a `font-size:0` in `ul` and need set a `font-size: em` in `li` child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I don't think you should do this.

But here's a way (a really dirty hack. Not recommended!) - writing `li/` would mean that `li` is self closing. So if you have `doctype html`, it would generate the desired output.

```
doctype html
...
ul
  li/
  |  1
  li/
  |  2
```

The output:

```
<ul>
  <li> 1
  <li> 2
</ul>
```

#### Again, you shouldn't do this. Just close the goddamn tag.

Comment: Thanks! It's work!
I should do this, because between `li` there are indents(spaces).
I can't write `font-size: 0` on `ul`. Because the in `li` child is necessary to specify the `font-size` in `em`.